# Make a javascript popup with clickable pictures?

Tags: javascript, popupwindow, clickable-image

Hello I have looked but I don't see what I am wondering. is there anyway I could make a popup appear using javascript on my website so it has a qr code on it? and maybe a clickable picture beside it to use for computer users? is this possible or?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.  Either show us code, or your question is likely to be deleted per the StackOverflow guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bootstrap` modals. Modals are dialog prompts. You may add pictures, buttons, links, probably all HTML elements...

[Example Bootstrap Modals](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Comment: Hello thanks for the help I appreciate it but how do I add a clickable image to the code for bootstrap?

Comment: Easy [screenshot](http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1406/fe/a75e53efc60e.png). <a href="#"><img src="http://www.qrstuff.com/images/sample.png" height="40px" width="40px"></a>